# Drop Frames from the camera preview

Tags: android, android-camera

I am using Camera 1 and I understand that I get range of supported frame rate and set that frame. However I want the preview to be showing on very low frame rate (ie 5 frames per second).

I can't set that as it is below any range. Is there a way I can drop certain frame from the preview? If setPreviewCallbackwithbuffer then I get the frame but at that point it is already displayed. Any way I can just "skip frames" from preview?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot intervene in frames on preview surface. You could do some tricks if you use TextureSurface for preview, but if you need very low frame rate, you can simply draw the frames (preferably, to an OpenGL texture) yourself. You will get the YUV frames in [onPreveiewFrame()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html#onPreviewFrame(byte[],%20android.hardware.Camera)) callback, and pass them for display when you want. You can use a shader to display the YUV frames without waisting CPU to convert them to RGB.

Usually, we want to skip preview frames because we want to run some CV algorithms on the frames, and often we want to display the frames modified by such CV processing, e.g. with bounding boxes of detected objects. Even if you have the coordinates of the box aside, and want to display the preview frame 'as is', using your own renderer has the advantage that there will be no time lag between the picture and the overlay.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I want to do and for the exact same reason.  You hit the nail on the head .but do you have ANY example or turorial on how to do this using textureView ?